# Reference Error from echo date

Tags: javascript, php

I'm getting a

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Thursday is not defined
```

from this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var date = <?php echo date("l"); ?>;
</script>
```

Am I not drinking enough coffee today?

Comment: Use quotes `var date = '<?php echo date("l"); ?>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing the date as a string. Try this:

```
var date = '<?php echo date("l"); ?>';
```

and I'd need a measure of coffee consumption, weight, length of sleep, and a detailed medical history to accurately answer how much coffee you should consume.

Comment: syntax error.. close the quotes.

Comment: That's it. Do I want to use single quotes around 'l'?

Comment: You can use single quotes around l, escape the quotes \"l\" or use single quotes around the whole thing. Single and double quotes are interchangeable here, easiest solution is just to wrap one with singles and one with doubles.

Answer (score 1):

You're dumping PHP output directly into a Javascript context, which means you have to generate VALID javascript code:

```
var date = <?php echo json_encode(date('l')); ?>;
```

Right now you're generating the equivalent of:

```
var date = Thursday;
```

Since you haven't put any quotes on that string, JS is treating that as an undefined variable. It should have been

```
var date = 'Thursday';
```

and json_encode() will take care of doing that for you.

Answer (score 0):

use '' or "" to a store a string

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var date = '<?php echo date("l"); ?>';
</script>
```